# Append inline scripts inside Twig layout block

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, fosuserbundle

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

  <!-- Omitted -->

  <div class="content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </div>

  <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
  {% block javascripts %}
    <!-- I want to be able to inject inline scripts from sub-templates here -->
  {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

Then I have the register_content.html.twig template overridden from FOSUserBundle and in it I am trying to inject script into the "javascripts" block like so:

```
{% block javascripts %}
  <script>
    // Some inline JS
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem I am having is the inline script seems to get injected at the end of the "body" block and not in the "scripts" block.

This is the output I am getting:

```
      <!-- This should be below js/vendor.js scripts -->      
      <script>
        // Some inline JS
      </script>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Does my problem lie with FOSUserBundle and it's own templates it inherits from (it still uses my layout and everything I have in it; not it's own layout). I'm very confused here.

P.S. I'm total newbie to Symfony/Twig so please be easy on me.

EDIT: These are the FOSUserBundle layout and templates I have overriden:

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'AcmeWebBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Acme Demo Application{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}        
    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% parent() %}
{% endblock %}
```

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</div>

<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register form-horizontal">
    <!-- HTML Omitted --> 
</form>

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/public/js/app.js' %}
    <script>
        // jQuery is undefined because it gets defined below the 'javascripts' block in the parent layout
        console.dir(window.jQuery);
    </script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The template with `{% block scripts %}` extends the last layout you've added right? And the last layout extends the first one you've shown? See what happens if you define empty `{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}` in FOSUserBundle's layout.

Comment: Actually, that was a mistake. The block is called "javascripts" in both places, I have corrected my original question. Also, removing the {{ parent() }} from the FOSUserBundle layout template makes no difference.

Comment: Can you show the entire code of how you are overriding the register_content.html.twig template from FOSUserBundle?

Comment: why not just use a file name `custom.js` in your asset and put all your scripts there.

Comment: @GentiSaliu I have updated my question with relevant FOSUserBundle layout and templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the EDIT the situation is more clear.

The behaviour you expect works with template inheritance only; it won't work with `include`, the way you have it in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig`.

To do what you want, do one of the following:

- Place the inline JavaScript code from the `javascript` block of `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig` inside the `javascript` block of `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig`
- Let template `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig` inherit from `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig` and override its blocks as needed (`register_content.html.twig` does not extend `layout.html.twig`, so this does not make much sense)